# JavaScript Regex return null

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that look like this :

```
blablablablafunction tr(b){b=b.split("");b=b.reverse();b=b.slice(2);return b.join("")}blablablabla
```

And i want to get : `b=b.split("");b=b.reverse();b=b.slice(2);return b.join("")`

with `Regex` :

```
var match = "function tr(b){(.*)}";
var f = html.match(match);
```

And i get null in `f`.Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to escape special characters in the regex in this case I believe these are `{` , `}` and also `(` and `)`(around the function argument list). Use the escape character(`\`) to do that. So try this regex:

```
var match = "function tr\\(b\\)\\{(.*)\\}";
```

Comment: do you have any example?