# RegEx returning null after excecuting?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to remove a wrapper around a button using RegExr, but it returns a null value.

I used the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression?rq=1) question, like so:

```
var title = $( ".redButton" ).text();
var myString = $( "#content" ).html();
var myRegexp = /(<p>\s<button class"redButton">)((?:\s|.{1,50})*)(<.button>\s<.p>)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);

console.log(match);
```

so i can eventually turn this:

```
<article id="content">
    <p>
        <button class="redButton">EEN HELE LANG TITEL IN EEN KNOP</button>
    </p>
</article>
```

into this:

```
<article id="content">
        <button class="redButton">LONG TITLE IN A BUTTON</button>
</article>
```

Before I continued I wanted to check if the RegEx worked, which it apparently doesn't. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097699/javascript-regex-return-null) solution would fix the problem, using escapes, but I don't understand when I should and when I shouldn't escape.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Rule 1, do not use regex to parse HTML... rule 2, if you really need to parse HTML with regex see rule 1

Comment: you're using JavaScript, so just use the DOM to interact with the HTML. Regex is a terrible solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the immediate parents of an element use the jQuery method [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). Run the snippet then inspect the button in devtools and you'll see the paragraph tags have been removed.

```js
const $button = $('#content .redButton');
$button.unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="content">
  <p>
    <button class="redButton">EEN HELE LANG TITEL IN EEN KNOP</button>
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: No idea. It actually does what I want but way easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions and HTML generally don't work well together. Why not use `DOMParser` instead? Parse the string into a document, append the `button` to the `article`, then remove the `p`:

```js
const htmlStr = `<article id="content">
    <p>
        <button class="redButton">EEN HELE LANG TITEL IN EEN KNOP</button>
    </p>
</article>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');
const button = doc.querySelector('.redButton');
const parentToRemove = button.parentElement;
const ancestorToAppendTo = parentToRemove.parentElement;
ancestorToAppendTo.appendChild(button);
parentToRemove.remove();
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

This will append the button to it's *parent's parent*, and remove it's *parent* from the HTML.